# Anyone have an alternative dowload site for a fastboot binary?

Tags: linux, fastboot

I'm working on rooting my android kernel and most sites list http://android-dls.com/files/linux/fastboot as the place to look for the fastboot binary. However, I've been getting a 404 (Page not Found) error when attempting to access this site.

Does anyone know of an alternate download location for fastboot?

I'm currently running Ubuntu Linux.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTC used to have a copy of the Linux binary, but they changed their developers portal and now I can't find that one anymore, either. The only other pre-compiled version I've been able to find is [here](http://berz.me/other/bionic/fastboot/fastboot-linux) (link originated from [this thread on droidforums.net](http://www.droidforums.net/forum/droid-bionic-hacks/171623-guide-return-stock-recover-brick-using-new-file-format-fxz.html), which also has a link to a pre-compiled OSX binary).

I checked with `readelf` on my Linux VM and it looks like it's a 64-bit binary, so I've also uploaded a 32-bit version to my Dropbox public folder, and it can be downloaded [here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/16958605/fastboot). This is the binary I use on my machine, which I believe I got from the aforementioned HTC site that's now missing.

Aside from that, you can compile Android from source to get it...but that's kind of a terrible solution for a single small binary file.

Comment: I'd just use someone else's hard work, someone who makes their builds available - see my answer. :P

Answer (score 8):

The Replicant Project builds tools with every release; you can find their tools [here](http://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/replicant/images/) (go down the directory tree in a path like `replicant-2.3/preview/0002/tools/`), along with notes about which git version was used for the source. Go one directory up and read COPYING for details.

Note: They only offer Linux builds.

Source code is [here](http://gitorious.org/replicant).

Comment: This one worked for me (and it's reasonably trustable).

Answer (score 4):

You want [the Android SDK](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html).  From the [CyanogenMod wiki](http://wiki.cyanogenmod.com/wiki/Fastboot):

> After installing the Android SDK or ADB Standalone you can use 'fastboot' in addition to the more common ADB.

After installing the SDK you will [need to add](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/adding-packages.html) the Android SDK platform-tools package.

Answer (score 1):

Here it is: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=11347040&postcount=105

Comment: Can't say I'd trust this binary - it's the right size, but I'm not giving that root access on a box I care about.

Comment: @Broam I found what appears to be the source.  Slightly more reputable; you can review [the thread](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=537508&page=11) and see if anyone else complained about it, at least.

Comment: Yes, that is where I found it.